# Subject that emits events to subscribers in specific order with back-pressure

Tags: scala, system.reactive, rx-java, monifu

Imagine a pipe of subscribers that you emit event to and it visits one subscriber after another.

Having a PublishSubject and x subscribers/observables. Normally events are emitted to observers in a specific order but simultaneously regardless of when observers return. Is it possible to do this flow :

1. emit event to observerA
2. after osbserverA returns, emit the event to observerB
3. after observerB returns, emit the event to observerC

I'm using [RxScala](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala) and [Monifu](https://github.com/monifu/monifu) Rx implementations

Monifu even has a back-pressure implementation :

```
def onNext(elem: T): Future[Ack]
```

I'd like to see "**And Result was : Changed !!**" be printed out in this sample:

```
  val subject = PublishSubject[Int]()

  var result = "Not Changed"
  subject.subscribe { i =>
    Observable.timerOneTime(3.seconds, Continue).asFuture.map { x =>
      result = "Changed !!"
      x.get
    }
  }

  subject.subscribe { i =>
    Observable.timerOneTime(1.seconds, Continue).asFuture.map { x =>
      println("And Result was : " + result)
      x.get
    }
  }

  subject.onNext(1)
```

Is it possible in RxScala/RxJava or Monifu without extending Subject and overriding onNext implementation? These classes are declared final anyway so it would be rather hacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is a custom Subject implementation, something like this in Monifu that would feed the observers in a flatMap manner (ignoring the fact that [PublishSubject](https://github.com/alexandru/monifu/blob/master/shared/monifu-rx/src/main/scala/monifu/reactive/subjects/PublishSubject.scala) is a final class) :

```
class PipeSubject extends PublishSubject[RxEvent] {
  override def onNext(elem: RxEvent): Future[Ack] = {
    if (!isCompleted) {
      val observers = subscriptions
      if (observers.nonEmpty)
        pipeThroughMany(observers, elem)
      else
        Continue
    }
    else
      Cancel
  }

 private[this] def pipeThroughMany(array: Array[Observer[T]], elem: T): Future[Continue] = {
    val length = array.length
    def >>>(idx: Int = 0): Future[Continue] = {
      val obs = array(idx)
      obs.onNext(elem).flatMap {
         case Continue =>
           if (idx+1 < length)
              >>>(idx+1)
           else
             Continue
         case _ =>
           removeSubscription(obs)
           Continue
      }
    }
    >>>()
  }
}
```